# Google chrome geolocation not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm working on cross platform application. navigator.geolocation was working fine, but since last 2 days it just giving problem in Google chrome.
Is the api deprecated or some other issue for this api? I tested following code on many different browsers and network but still the same issue.

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

ERROR(2): Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403.

Comment: http://www.googleapis.com doesn't exist. https://ajax.googleapis.com does. Are you trying [to use one of these libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)?

Comment: Do you also get ... `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Chrome 44 on OS X latest. I've received the insecure deprecation warning on external sites, but no such warning when running locally (via file:// protocol or localhost). Same 403 error, same message.

Comment: No, it just giving me one error:
ERROR(2): Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403.

Comment: Yeah, I think that might be the issue. 2 months ago chrome 43 also changes some api's, that caused problems in scrolling in sencha touch.

Comment: The problem is down to authenticating with the Google geolocation API. Some help can be found here: http://onefinepub.com/2015/04/fix-chromium-network-location-provider-returning-error-code-403/

Answer (score 1):

Latest chrome has deprecated this API on non-secure origins:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Time to get `https://localhost` up and running ;)

For future queries...
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en

Comment: I don't think so this, this also fails for me on localhost which is defined as a secured domain.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed now.  Must have been an issue due to a server-side change google made.  When I was debugging I was seeing a rate limit issue, even when I ran the getCurrentPosition() call in console on https://www.google.com.